# unable to install e-paper display, module epd2in7 not found

Tags: hardware, screen, modules

I bought a 2.7inch e-Paper HAT,

I install everything but when I try to run a code I have

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import epd2in7
ImportError: No module named epd2in7
```

any idea how to fix that? 
To be fair I have no experience with raspberry hardware (just software)
I just would like to display a clock

that the official https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.7inch_e-Paper_HAT

I also found a another one https://diyprojects.io/test-waveshare-epaper-eink-2-7-spi-screen-raspberry-pi-python/ but always have this epd2in7 error

Comment: `No module named epd2in7` ... it is software related  ...  just download and install that module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `epd2in7` module is indeed available from the [second tutorial you linked](https://diyprojects.io/test-waveshare-epaper-eink-2-7-spi-screen-raspberry-pi-python/).

They ask you to run the following:

```
wget https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/f/f5/2.7inch-e-paper-hat-code.7z
```

And extract the 7-Zip file with

```
7za e 2.7inch-e-paper-hat-code.7z
```

Then go to the `raspberrypi/python` directory:

```
cd raspberrypi/python
```

[Note: there is a typo in the tutorial as it asks you to `cd /raspberrypi/python`; if you did this, you would end up in a non-existent directory because of the leading `/` pointing to the root of the file system]

If you list the files in `raspberrypi/python` with `ls`, you should notice an `epd2in7.py` file among others. That is the missing module you were looking for. If you create and run your script there, it will work just fine (as the tutorial suggests you do). Alternatively you could add the directory to your `PYTHONPATH` so that you can resolve it in any directory.

Comment: My `raspberrypi` directory is empty. I have both `raspberrypi` and `python`--but not in the same directory. And my `epd2in7.py` file is actually `epd2in7b.py` in the main directory. Both the `raspberrypi` and `python` directories are empty.